# How to Zoom in and Zoom out ImageViews of in a scrollView

Tags: ios, ios6, uiscrollview, uitapgesturerecognizer, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I have a scrollview in which i m showing all the imageViews from an imageArray and i have done paging enabled. Now i want to zoom in and zoom out the images in the scrollview. Can someone tel me whats the best way on doing it ??

Comment: Would you require to zoom all the images or selected image from that scroll view?

Answer (score 3):

You can-not zoom in and out of a scrollview built for paging, you can only slide between pages... you need to nest another UIScrollView within that first "paging" scroll view that is built for zooming (i.e. paging is disabled and multi-touch and zoom is enabled)

Answer (score 0):

There's a [WWDC 2010](https://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.4092349126.04109539109.4144345585?i=1699219987) video which have very nice tutorial for UIScrollView.This tutorial have very efficent techniques to do paging with zoom enable.Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412758/how-can-i-provide-zoomin-zoomout-paging-functionality-in-to-uiscrollview) also